# Align images always look same whenever change position each other

Tags: html, css, image, position, alignment

I'm trying to align images in `div` box sized of 900 px and all images has different width. But the problem happen when I change orders of images, margin between images should been looked same like before.

Does anyone know some tips to solve this problem?

```
<ul class="icons">
    <li class="icon-kid left"><img src="img/icon_kid.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li class="icon-wifi"><img src="img/icon_wifi.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li class="icon-time"><img src="img/icon_time.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li class="icon-park right"><img src="img/icon_park.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is your code which have problem?

Comment: i edited and theres no problem in markup i think. i dnt know how to style this code

Comment: class icons have width of 900px and all li has different widths. first li and the last li should been positioned each left and right and others been positioned regularly.

Comment: create a demo fiddle, that might help to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For images you can use nth-child css.
Add **nth-child** in li. You don't need to add additional class in li.

li:nth-child(n).